# Facebook helper not appearing in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-like

I created a new test project in MVC4 to test if I could use Facebook Helper from the Nuget gallery.  I followed the instructions which are very simple, point and click to install the Facebook helper from Nuget, edit your page, and insert like button.

When I run the project I can actually see the facebook likebutton being generated when I view it through firebug, but it does not appear on the page.

**Here is my default index page**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <p>
                To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit
                <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
                The page features <mark>videos, tutorials, and samples</mark> to help you get the most from ASP.NET MVC.
                If you have any questions about ASP.NET MVC visit
                <a href="http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx/1?MVC" title="ASP.NET MVC Forum">our forums</a>.
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
}
<h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
<div>
    @Facebook.LikeButton()
</div>
```

I´ve gone through several pages regarding Facebook helper and they all describe the process in the same way.  Does anyone know if I should config any files before using this library?

**Edited:**

I will paste my html code that is loaded into the markup after execution.  I will abbreviate some scripts and stuff since it has many hundreds of line of code  :)

```
<html id="facebook" class="" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
<script>
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A13876%2F&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=src&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80&amp;font&amp;locale=en_US&amp;ref&amp;_fb_noscript=1" /></noscript>
<meta content="noodp, noydir" name="robots">
<meta id="meta_referrer" content="default" name="referrer">
<meta content="Facebook is a social utility that connects people with friends and others who work, study and live around them. People use Facebook to keep up with friends, upload an unlimited number of photos, post links and videos, and learn more about the people they meet." name="description">
<link href="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A13876%2F&layout=standard&show_faces=src&width=450&action=like&colorscheme=light&height=80&font&locale=en_US&ref" media="handheld" rel="alternate">
<title>Facebook</title>
<link href="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yc/r/-WUN6qLbp5n.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yf/r/gd49XKRAMNQ.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yc/r/XaOowWd9_Aq.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yH/r/Dpn1SKTH3-z.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yB/r/Vm1JnKckidu.js">
<script src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y-/r/ARN_8tuLdws.js">
<script src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yq/r/XboiPeV3jQI.js">
<script>
<script>
<script src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yP/r/eTzqwp1jxjF.js" async="">
<script src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yh/r/aTzvHAZI_Jd.js" async="">
</head>
<body class="plugin ff4 win Locale_en_US">
<div id="FB_HiddenContainer" style="position:absolute; top:-10000px; width:0px; height:0px;"></div>
<script>
<script>
<script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

See where in the Url it generates (link href="https://www.facebook...) it says "&show_faces=src"
That causes the problem; it should be "&show_faces=true"

Even though true is supposed to be the default, if you have this issue try changing it to:  `@Facebook.LikeButton(showFaces: false)`

EDIT: this only helps if you set it to false. Same issue with LikeBox and all boolean properties.

Comment: thanks, there is one more thing i added to make it work @Facebook.LikeButton(href:"url to like", showFaces: false)

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML is being rendered I can only assume the problem it's a CSS problem, check the styling of the elements in FireBug and make sure they aren't being hidden e.g. check for `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` or make sure there isn't `float` applied which is taking it off the screen.

Comment: As you can see in the code above I have no such attributes.  I went through the Facebook.cshtml file to check if there are any visible or display attributes but I couldn´t find any.  I even tried changing the html using firebug during run time, just to see if I could make the facebook button appear, I even tried changing the style to min-height:500px but nothing appeared  :(

Comment: @gardarvalur you don't have styling on the surrounding `<div>` however the HTML generated (I assume) will be adding styling etc. My guess is that styling is clashing with your site CSS causing the content to be hidden (whether that be due to it being moved, no height or hidden). Could you post what HTML is generated by the `LikeButton()` method?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @James, I´ve edited my post to show the html for the facebook link  :)

Comment: But as you say, I might need to double check my css just to be sure.

Comment: @gardarvalur it could be the fact your trying to render an inner html doc, but that's probably not the case. I would check the console in FireBug I would stab a guess at one of the scripts not being downloaded (i.e. cross-origin issue). Try hosting the `LikeButton()` code in an iframe see if it works.

Comment: Hello again @James.  Even wrapping it in iFrame blocks did not work.  I´ve been searching for guidelines in using Facebook Helper with Webmatrix and they all come up with the same instructions (which I have followed).  But as you say, this is probably just some minor glitch somewhere within my code that I can´t pinpoint :/  Thank you for all your help though :)